# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory when I download a .jpg using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am building a discord bot using a nodejs server and discordjs, and one of the things I am trying to do is pass in a .jpg discord link (ie, https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/537413376389939223/593608396113051653/GiveEmTheWorm.png) to the npm module jpeg-js so that I can hopefully retrieve the color of particular pixels.

I attempted to solve this by downloading the image located at the link above. I used other methods as well, but they all led to various different errors. Other stackoverflow topics with similar errors unfortunately did not contain anything that helped me. If anyone has a better way of downloading images in nodejs and/or a smarter way to get the color of pixels, please let me know!

```
//attempt to download 
let download = function(uri, filename, callback){
request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
};
//the actual function call
download(`[the path above]`, 'file.jpg', function(){
 console.log('done');
});

//all that above so that I can hopefully do
let jpegData = fs.readFileSync('file.jpg');
let rawImageData = jpeg.decode(jpegData);
console.log(rawImageData);

//which will (in theory) allow me to inspect specific pixels.
```

expected result: I want the file to be downloaded in the root directory of this program so that the secondary part of it can decode the jpeg into something I can modify.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzEh4.jpg

---

edit: I am still getting the same error, so here is my updated code (and I made the snippet a little bigger)

```
    let download = function(uri, filename, callback){
      request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
         console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
         console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
         request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
         });
    };

    someOtherFunction()
    {
       let pokePath = 'thisisthebiglinkabove'
        console.log(pokePath);
        download(pokePath, 'nameoffile.jpg', function(){
          let jpegData = fs.readFileSync(filename);
          let rawImageData = jpeg.decode('nameoffile.jpg');
          console.log(rawImageData);
          console.log('done');
        });
    },
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L838i.jpg

Comment: `download` is asynchronous. Move the last three lines into where `console.log('done')` is.

Comment: did this, still getting an error :(

Comment: The image at the link you provided is a png, not jpg.

Comment: the one I was testing is a .jpg